# Why can fully detached teeth be re-attached, and yet if you break / crack your Maxillary-first-premolar the only option is extraction and disposal?

Tags: oral-health

Why can completely detached ( de-attached ) teeth be so easily re-attached by dentists, and yet if you break / crack your Maxillary-first-premolar right up / down the middle ( so that one half moves freely sideways ) the only option is extraction and disposal ?​